# Do I need to include interaction in the model when I am only interested in overall effect?

Tags: regression, interaction, interpretation, meta-analysis

Say I am doing a linear model, with treatment and study effects, and I know the treatment effects are different across studies.

I want to estimate the OVERALL treatment effect (NOT study-specific ones).

Now there are two models in my consideration:

```
Model 1: E(Y) = TRT + STUDY
Model 2: E(Y) = TRT + STUDY + TRT * STUDY
```

My question is:

Do I need to use Model 2 (with the interaction term) when I know I'm only interested in estimating the OVERALL treatment effect? Will model 1 be good enough since it will give me the average treatment effects across studies anyway?

Comment: My guess is you don't really want to use a standard regression model at all. You want to do a meta-analysis. Certainly it will be true that the effect will differ between studies due to randomness, but if you think the studies truly differ beyond randomness, you just need a mixed-effects meta-analysis, which is pretty common. One of our MA experts should be able to explain this for you.

Comment: @gung is probably right that, in this particular case, a meta-analytic model is probably the best way. That said, I still think this is a sort of an interesting question for the cases where the categories being aggregated over are not studies, but rather some other categorical factor, in which case a meta-analytic model may not make sense. This may not be the case the OP is interested in, but it would at least match the title.

Comment: @JakeWestfall, that's true, & it's what I initially had in mind. You could ask yourself as a new question, if you wanted. (You could also provide your own answer, if that's what you had in mind.)

Comment: Suppose one of the two models you propose is appropriate: An advantage of including interaction is that its inclusion will reduce the error mean square term, which is the denominator of the F-ratio for judging significance of main effects. So including interaction may increase power enough to change conclusions about main effects. // This benefit accrues whether or not you're interested in interpreting interaction. But if interaction is significant (and important in size), you should ponder what that implies about main effects.

Comment: @gung as I understand it this is comparing two models on the same data-set, not trying to work with many different primary studies so I suspect that the answer has something to do with marginality not meta-analysis. But I must say I am not clear about the scenario.

Comment: @mdewey, it's not entirely clear. I'm focusing on "the treatment effects are different across studies". To me that implies different primary studies. But if you don't think so, maybe this isn't clear enough & needs to be put on hold. Do you want to ask the OP for the information that would clarify the issues for you?

Comment: Do you have one data-set to which you wish to fit two different models in which case @BruceET comments, especially the last one seem to me to be relevant?

Comment: I am voting to close this as unclear as the OP has not come back to clarify

Comment: Another possibility is that a multilevel model is needed.